# Default quantity on product page for configurable product with MOQ

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.9.1.0, quantity

I currently have my site setup with simple products with custom options but would like to change them to configurable products and take advantage of the Magento 1.9.1 swatch feature.

The problem I am seeing is that with configurable products the displayed default quantity on the product page is always "1" even though I have a `minimum order quantity (MOQ)` set on each simple product page.

All my products have a MOQ. The simple products of the configurable product always have the same MOQ. Is there anyway to display the MOQ on the configurable product page as the default quantity instead of "1"?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not achievable out of the box.

And I don't know any module which is doing this.

What you need to do is extend `Product.Config` to include all the MOQ of the simple items and then make sure, that your qty is checked againsti